# Python - Autocomplete extension for numbers and suggestion using random queries

Tags: python, algorithm, autocomplete

I have a very minimalistic code that performs autocompletion for input queries set by the user by storing a historical data of names(close to 1000) in a list. Right now, it gives suggestion in lexicographical smallest order.

The names stored in a list are (fictitious):

```
names = ["show me 7 wonders of the world","most beautiful places","top 10 places to visit","Population > 1000","Cost greater than 100"]
```

The queries given by the user can be:

```
queries = ["10", "greater", ">", "7 w"]
```

Current Implementation:

```
class Index(object):

    def __init__(self, words):
        index = {}
        for w in sorted(words, key=str.lower, reverse=True):
            lw = w.lower()
            for i in range(1, len(lw) + 1):
                index[lw[:i]] = w

        self.index = index

    def by_prefix(self, prefix):
        """Return lexicographically smallest word that starts with a given
        prefix.
        """ 
        return self.index.get(prefix.lower(), 'no matches found')

def typeahead(usernames, queries):
    users = Index(usernames)
    print "\n".join(users.by_prefix(q) for q in queries)
```

This works fine if the queries start with the pre-stored names. But fails to provide suggestions if a random entry is made(querying somewhere from the middle of string). It also does not recognize numbers and fails for that too.

I was wondering if there could be a way to include the above functionalities to improve my existing implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's O(n) but it works. Your function is checking if it starts with a prefix, but the behavior you describe you want is checking if the string contains the query

```
def __init__(self, words):
    self.index = sorted(words, key=str.lower, reverse=True)

def by_prefix(self, prefix):
    for item in self.index:
        if prefix in item:
            return item
```

This gives:

```
top 10 places to visit
Cost greater than 100
Population > 1000
show me 7 wonders of the world
```

Just for the record this takes `0.175` seconds on my pc for 5 queries of 1,000,005 records, with the last 5 records being the matching ones. (Worst case scenario)

Comment: That does fine. But I would like the queries to be case-insensitive. Currently it considers lowercase and uppercase differently.

Comment: just do`if prefix.lower() in item.lower()` then

Comment: Yep. That does it. Do you have any ideas for further improvement, like suggesting  the top 5 names for a given query?

Comment: If you wanna take it further I would suggest using a library, maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/.

Comment: Can't it be done without the help of an external library? I mean can't it sort and return 5 closest matches?

Comment: In theory you could get all the matches `x in y`, then figure out which is the closest using a sequence matcher, then sort by that and return the top 5 values. You are just going to be reinventing the wheel though, just use the library

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned by performance, you can use `if prefix in item:` for every `item` in your list `names`. This statement matches if prefix is part of the string item, e.g.:

```
prefix   item       match
'foo'    'foobar'   True
'bar'    'foobar'   True
'ob'     'foobar'   True
...
```

I think that this is the simplest way to achieve this, but clearly not the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add more entries to your index, e.g. for the item `"most beautiful places"`:

```
"most beautiful places"
"beautiful places"
"places"
```

If you do this, you also get matches if you start typing a word that's not the first word in the sentence. You can modify your code like this to do that:

```
class Index(object):

    def __init__(self, words):
        index = {}
        for w in sorted(words, key=str.lower, reverse=True):
            lw = w.lower()
            tokens = lw.split(' ')
            for j in range(len(tokens)):
                w_part = ' '.join(tokens[j:])
                for i in range(1, len(w_part) + 1):
                    index[w_part[:i]] = w

        self.index = index
```

The downside from this approach is that the index gets very large. You could also combine this approach with the one pointed out by Keatinge by storing 2-digit prefixes for every word in your index dictionary and store  a list of queries that contain this prefix as items of the index dictionary.

Comment: Agreed. Let's say in future I would want to show top 5 suggestions for a given query, would it still work?